# How do I fix my c# script that has suddenly stopped working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2d platforming game using Unity game engine, and I've run into an issue with my code. One of the game's core mechanics is a shield the player has most of the time, and previously I was able to change the position of this shield using the arrow keys and it was working fine, but now it has suddenly stopped and I can't figure out why. Is there anything here I'm overlooking that's causing it?

The shield's script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Shield : MonoBehaviour
{
  //Sets the player's movement script as an object to be called on within this script.
  public Player_Movement player;

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
      {
          if (player.crouch)
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
              HoldShieldSide();
          }
          else
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
              HoldShieldSide();
          }
      }

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
      {
          if (player.crouch)
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0);
            HoldShieldUp();
          }
          else
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 1.1f, 0);
              HoldShieldUp();
          }
      }

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
      {
          if (player.crouch)
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
              HoldShieldSide();
          }
          else
          {
              this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
              HoldShieldSide();
          }
      }
  }

  //Lowers the shield to be in front of the bottom box collider.
  public void LowerShield()
  {
      print("LowerShield function is being read.");

      //If the player is facing the right...
      if (player.transform.localScale.x == 1)
      { 
          //...set the shield to the right side when crouched.
          this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
          HoldShieldSide();
      }
      //If the player is facing the left...
      else if (player.transform.localScale.x == -1)
      {
          //...set the shield to the left side when crouched.
          this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
          HoldShieldSide();
      }
  }

 //Raises the shield to be in front of the top box collider.
  public void RaiseShield()
  {
      print("RaiseShield function is being read.");

      //If the player is facing the right...
      if (player.transform.localScale.x == 1)
      {
          //...set the shield to the right side when standing.
          this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
          HoldShieldSide();
      }
      //If the player is facing the left...
      else if (player.transform.localScale.x == -1)
      {
          //...set the shield to the left side when standing.
          this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
          HoldShieldSide();
      }
  }

  //Keep the shield at its default rotation.
  public void HoldShieldSide()
  {
      this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
  }

  //Rotate the shield by 90 degrees.
  public void HoldShieldUp()
  {
      this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "stopped working". What is happening that shouldn't, what isn't happening that should? What did you change, or what else changed between the previous working state and now?

Comment: When I push the directional arrow keys while crouching it should move the shield's position relative to the player, however now it only works when I'm not crouched. I added in the "HoldShieldSide()" and "HoldShieldUp()" functions but those had no effect when I removed them. I also changed "if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))" to "if (player.crouch)", but that was after the shield no longer changed position while crouching. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Check the scale of your character which you seem to use to decide. Floats are not exact after all

Comment: To be more specific, the problem appears to be the script not executing the "this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -0.5f, 0);" portion specifically, as it had shown the requirements for this had been met when I added a print() command to see if it did, but it won't change the shield's position.

Comment: Both the player and the shield game objects have a scale of x=1 and y=1, is that going to cause issues?

Comment: You only get to adding - 0.6f, etc. when the scale is - 1, so if you're saying the scale is +1 then that's definitely the problem, but otherwise I'm with @BugFinder - replace exact comparisons like `player.transform.localScale.x == -1` with inequalities like `player.transform.localScale.x < 0` to make sure you hit the cases (because I'm pretty sure all you care about is polarity to determine if it's a mirror image or not).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tips I can give you to find the problem:
Check that no other scripts are checking the position of the shield.
You wrote the LowerShield () and RaiseShield () functions, but they both check if the player's localScale property is -1. This shouldn't be possible, because the scale of a GameObject must be positive
In the code shown you never use them, so try deleting them for now.
Insert in each block "if (player.crouch)", print to understand what happens.
Then if you still don't understand, send us the console output.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Shield : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Sets the player's movement script as an object to be called on within this script.
    public Player_Movement player;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (player.crouch)
            {
                print("LeftArrow  | " + "  Privious position:" + transform.position + "  |  New position: " + player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -0.5f, 0)));
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
                HoldShieldSide();
            }
            else
            {
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
                HoldShieldSide();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (player.crouch)
            {
                print("UpArrow  | " + "  Privious position:" + transform.position + "  |  New position: " + (player.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0)));
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0);
                HoldShieldUp();
            }
            else
            {
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 1.1f, 0);
                HoldShieldUp();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (player.crouch)
            {
                print("RightArrow  | " + "  Privious position:" + transform.position + "  |  New position: " + (player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, -0.5f, 0)));
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, -0.5f, 0);
                HoldShieldSide();
            }
            else
            {
                this.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.6f, 0.5f, 0);
                HoldShieldSide();
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Keep the shield at its default rotation.
    public void HoldShieldSide()
    {
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    }

    //Rotate the shield by 90 degrees.
    public void HoldShieldUp()
    {
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90f);
    }
}
```

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and vote positively. I would very much appreciate it :)**